# xamarin android XML layout not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to coding with xamarin android but the main layout axml file not showing designer view so I cant but items as a button, text view,...etc
as shown in the image below :

Here what I see only

[image: here what I see only]

I wanna see the page like this
 [image: i wanna see the page like this]

I try to reset all window but not working...

Comment: You need to correct wording. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: see the second image ... I cant see the item in the red circle ... when I open the main layout.axml only I cant switch to layout design to add the item from toolbox ...

Comment: Is this issue resolved? i too had same issue

Comment: yes i reinstall vs and work

Answer (score 0):

You should go in solution explorer, right click the layout folder in Resources folder then add item and then choose android layout and then add.